# Set a property value from an expression in WiX

Tags: properties, wix

Can I define a WiX property that will have a value computed from other properties? For example, I have two properties:

```
<Property Id="SEARCH1">
  <RegistrySearch ... />
</Property>

<Property Id="SEARCH2">
  <RegistrySearch ... />
</Property>
```

I want to avoid copy-pasting a condition like `SEARCH1 = "" AND SEARCH2 = ""` across multiple places in my WiX source. Defining a derived property does not seem to work:

```
<Property Id="FOUND_NOTHING">
  SEARCH1 = "" AND SEARCH2 = ""
</Property>
```

Is there a valid way to define such a derived property to use just `FOUND_NOTHING` as a condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With WiX you can do this by authoring [`<SetProperty>`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_setproperty.htm) element. Under the hood, it creates a special custom action and schedules it appropriately.

Comment: How can I schedule a SetProperty just after the RegistrySearch events complete?

Comment: Schedule it after the AppSearch standard action.